# How to color the dataframe values depending on a threshold?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a `df` as follows:

```
       a                    b                    c                    d
    NaN                     NaN                 NaN           14.534883720930232
    NaN                     NaN                 NaN           76.30813953488372
23.837209302325583  6.8313953488372094  5.959302325581396   12.5
5.377906976744186   4.215116279069767   6.8313953488372094  13.80813953488372
8.13953488372093    8.13953488372093    5.523255813953488   1.0174418604651163
2.0348837209302326  11.19186046511628   2.616279069767442   1.8895348837209303
30.377906976744185  7.122093023255814   6.104651162790698   57.70348837209303
2.4709302325581395  1.1627906976744187  1.1627906976744187  2.9069767441860463
1.8895348837209303  5.087209302325581   2.0348837209302326  16.424418604651162
10.465116279069768  5.523255813953488   2.4709302325581395  1.308139534883721
3.633720930232558   4.069767441860465   0.7267441860465116  13.953488372093023
7.412790697674419   8.575581395348838   9.30232558139535    42.151162790697676
32.122093023255815  9.30232558139535    4.215116279069767   2.0348837209302326
```

I would like to know if there is a way to `df` cells depending on a threshold condition.

I want to color the values that are greater than 10 as red and the ones that are less than 10 as green. And the `NaNs` as black.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried doing:

```
def color_negative_red(value):

  if value < 10:
    color = 'green'
  elif value >= 10:
    color = 'red'
  else:
    color = 'black'

  return 'color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df.style.applymap` applies CSS styles, so it is only useful if outputting to HTML or when working with tools like jupyter notebook. What is your required output?

Comment: The required output is that the values above 10 be colored red and the ones below 10 are green and `nans` are black

Comment: But where are you outputting `df` to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running fine and giving expected output. Please check your output by running code on [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/)

Comment: Your can use Spyder plugin to use Jupyter notebooks inside spyder. Check out here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook

Comment: Please upvote it, if it helps in your case so that others would get the benefit.